# How to set the bottom line border in tab bar

Tags: android

[set color display in image help me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDvmk.png)

How to set indicator color in tabhost

Answer (score 0):

In **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
  <activity android:name=".ActivityName" android:theme="@style/tabTheme"/>
```

**In values/styles.xml:**

```
  <style name="tabTheme" parent="android:style/Theme"> 
  <item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@style/Widget.TabWidget</item>
   </style> 
  <style name="Widget.TabWidget" parent="android:Theme"> 
  <item name="android:tabStripEnabled">false</item>
```

or

tabWidget in your xml file.
add following code

```
android:tabStripEnabled="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change programmatically like this way

```
tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor("YOUR COLOR CODE"));
```

Comment: I have use Tabhost catrol not TabLayout